# How to manual set the specified paragraph to compare in ediff

Tags: ediff

For example, the following case.
It seems the system mistakenly compare wrong paragraph.

What I want to compare, for example, is the `public static...` with `public static...`.
How can I do that? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried hitting `n` until you see `public static...` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type <kbd>=</kbd> to invoke `ediff-inferior-compare-regions`

Tell it that you *don't* want to compare the current highlighted regions, and Ediff will ask you to select the regions that you *do* want to compare.

After exiting the inferior ediff session, return to the ediff control buffer for the original session and type <kbd>C-l</kbd> to resume it, and <kbd>!</kbd> to recalculate the regions.

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(ediff) Quick Help Commands` <kbd>RET</kbd>